# VR One bug on iPhone 6

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrone

I've been using the VR One Unity demo and am having an issue rendering correctly on iPhone 6 – only one eye is getting rendered. It renders just fine inside Unity, showing both eyes rendered correctly. I've linked in SceneKit and it's compiling just fine in Xcode.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has any idea what might be going on? I'm running Unity 4.6.3 on Mac (Yosemite 10.10.2), compiling to an iPhone 6 (iOS 8.1.3) using Xcode (6.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

Probably **Unity** version is wrong , try **4.5.4**
There are issues on the latest versions.

Comment: I switched back to 4.5.4 like you suggested and now it works just fine. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Project Settings > Player > Configuration > Graphics API > Open GL ES 2.0

This problem occurs with the new iOs Metal Rendering released with Unity 4.6.3.

Comment: FYI: iphone 5s renders with metal in unity 5.0.0f4. (w/o distortion or vignette). iphone 6, just renders a black screen with Metal. VRone sdk commit 59b5f9f