# ZEISS VR ONE SDK only one eye is getting rendered

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vrone

Good morning everyone, I'm trying to run the demo scene of the Zeiss VR ONE SDK 1.3 using unity3d 5.2.2, however, only one eye is getting rendered when running on Samsung S6, the solution that has been posted in this discussion [VR One bug on iPhone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730523/vr-one-bug-on-iphone-6)
requires the use of the unity 4.5.4, but in my case I absolutely need the SDK running on unity 5.2.2

[Result obtaining on the unity editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc5jE.png)

[Result obtaining on the S6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s28M9.jpg)

I appreciate your help and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Thank you artgb I have added two images of the result that I had on both Unity 5.2.2 editor and the Samsung S6

Comment: Why use the Zeiss sdk? Use Google's stuff: https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/

Comment: I have run a project first with google cardboard, but when I put the phone in the glasses the result is a little bit blur at the border, I want to use the VROne SDK which, I think, gives better result.